# Replace the 0 in a column with groupby median in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below. which is a sales data of two health care product starting from December 2016 to November 2018.

```
product     profit      bougt_date      discount    salary
   A         50         2016-12-01      5           25
   A         50         2017-01-03      4           20
   B         200        2016-12-24      10          100
   A         50         2017-01-18      3           0
   B         200        2017-01-28      15          80
   A         50         2017-01-18      6           15
   B         200        2017-01-28      20          0
   A         50         2017-04-18      6           0
   B         200        2017-12-08      25          0
   A         50         2017-11-18      6           20
   B         200        2017-08-21      20          90
   B         200        2017-12-28      30          110
   A         50         2018-03-18      10          0
   B         300        2018-06-08      45          100
   B         300        2018-09-20      50          60
   A         50         2018-11-18      8           45
   B         300        2018-11-28      35          0
```

From the above I would like replace 0 salary with groupby median of the the column product.

Explanation:

```
A :  15, 20, 20, 25, 45
 So the median = 20.



B :  60, 80, 90, 100, 100, 110
 So the median = 95.
```

Expected Output

```
product     profit      bougt_date      discount    salary
   A         50         2016-12-01      5           25
   A         50         2017-01-03      4           20
   B         200        2016-12-24      10          100
   A         50         2017-01-18      3           20
   B         200        2017-01-28      15          80
   A         50         2017-01-18      6           15
   B         200        2017-01-28      20          95
   A         50         2017-04-18      6           20
   B         200        2017-12-08      25          95
   A         50         2017-11-18      6           20
   B         200        2017-08-21      20          90
   B         200        2017-12-28      30          110
   A         50         2018-03-18      10          20
   B         300        2018-06-08      45          100
   B         300        2018-09-20      50          60
   A         50         2018-11-18      8           45
   B         300        2018-11-28      35          95
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this using masking `0` values using [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and use [`np.nanmedian`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.nanmedian.html) here.

```
fill_vals = df.salary.mask(df.salary.eq(0)).groupby(df['product']).transform(np.nanmedian)
df.assign(salary = df.salary.mask(df.salary.eq(0), fill_vals))

   product  profit  bougt_date  discount  salary
0        A      50  2016-12-01         5      25
1        A      50  2017-01-03         4      20
2        B     200  2016-12-24        10     100
3        A      50  2017-01-18         3      20
4        B     200  2017-01-28        15      80
5        A      50  2017-01-18         6      15
6        B     200  2017-01-28        20      95
7        A      50  2017-04-18         6      20
8        B     200  2017-12-08        25      95
9        A      50  2017-11-18         6      20
10       B     200  2017-08-21        20      90
11       B     200  2017-12-28        30     110
12       A      50  2018-03-18        10      20
13       B     300  2018-06-08        45     100
14       B     300  2018-09-20        50      60
15       A      50  2018-11-18         8      45
16       B     300  2018-11-28        35      95
```

**OR**

Using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['salary'] = (np.where(df['salary']==0,df['salary'].replace(0,np.nan).
                groupby(df['product']).transform('median'),df['salary']))
```

Answer (score 1):

first use `.groupby` and `.transform` the column to shown the grouped by median. Finally, locate salaries that are 0 with `.loc` and set them equal to the median salary.

```
#NOTE - the below line of code uses `median` instead of `np.nanmedian`. These will return different results...
#To anyone reading this, please know which one to use according to your situation...
#As you can see the outputs are different between Chester's answer and mine.
df.loc[df['salary'] == 0, 'salary'] = df.groupby('product')['salary'].transform('median')
df
```

output:

```
    product profit bougt_date discount salary
0   A   50  2016-12-01  5   25.0
1   A   50  2017-01-03  4   20.0
2   B   200 2016-12-24  10  100.0
3   A   50  2017-01-18  3   17.5
4   B   200 2017-01-28  15  80.0
5   A   50  2017-01-18  6   15.0
6   B   200 2017-01-28  20  80.0
7   A   50  2017-04-18  6   17.5
8   B   200 2017-12-08  25  80.0
9   A   50  2017-11-18  6   20.0
10  B   200 2017-08-21  20  90.0
11  B   200 2017-12-28  30  110.0
12  A   50  2018-03-18  10  17.5
13  B   300 2018-06-08  45  100.0
14  B   300 2018-09-20  50  60.0
15  A   50  2018-11-18  8   45.0
16  B   300 2018-11-28  35  80.0
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted :) This should do the trick though.

Comment: This gives the wrong output, right? You get median to be 17.5 and 80.0 (Not downvoter)

Comment: not sure why the output is different. I assumed the OP made a mistake when calculating the median (crying emoji). I'll have to investigate unless someone can spot. Kind of strange. @Danish ouput is in -- strange why it's a slightly different number. As you can see, I clearly grouped by the median. This isn't some custom function that I created. It's a pandas function.

Comment: The difference is `median` vs. `np.nanmedian` in @Ch3steR 's answer, so that would be the reason for the difference. Leaving my answer as is, with a comment in the answer, so that people can see the difference between `median` and `np.nanmedian`.

Comment: @DavidErickson here you have calculated the median including all zeros.